# How to analyze Debug Diagnostic Tool v2.0 dumps on 2003 Server x86

Tags: windows-server-2003, debugging, x86

Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2 comes with a log analyzer (sometimes).  I can't find the analyzer component in Debug Diagnostic 2.0 when installed on 2003 Server x86.

What's the recommended way to analyze the dump files without reverting to 1.2?

--

On x86 Win 2003 Server the Debug Diag 2.0 folder listing contains *less files* than the x64 version of the same application. Show below. Both machines have .NET 4 installed.

Win 2003 Svr x86 listing of Debug Diag 2.0

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\DebugDiag

2/03/2013  06:51 PM              .
2/03/2013  06:51 PM              ..
9/26/2013  11:36 AM         2,624,104 dbgeng.dll
9/26/2013  11:36 AM         1,129,576 dbghelp.dll
9/25/2013  11:19 AM           550,328 DbgHost.exe
9/25/2013  11:19 AM           331,192 DbgSvc.exe
9/26/2013  11:36 AM         3,337,666 DebugDiag.chm
9/25/2013  11:19 AM         2,864,056 DebugDiag.Collection.exe
9/25/2013  11:19 AM           158,136 LeakTrack.dll
2/03/2013  05:55 PM              Logs
9/26/2013  11:37 AM               331 Register.bat
2/03/2013  05:45 PM              Samples
2/03/2013  05:48 PM              Scripts
9/26/2013  11:36 AM           105,744 symsrv.dll
9/26/2013  11:36 AM                 1 symsrv.yes
9/26/2013  11:37 AM               365 Unregister.bat
             11 File(s)     11,101,499 bytes
              5 Dir(s)   6,770,343,936 bytes free
```

Win 7 Prof x64 listing of Debug Diag 2.0

```
C:\Program Files\DebugDiag>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 40A7-090C

 Directory of C:\Program Files\DebugDiag

03/12/2013  06:48 PM              .
03/12/2013  06:48 PM              ..
03/12/2013  06:42 PM              AnalysisRules
25/09/2013  10:31 AM            48,128 ClrMemDiagExt.dll
26/09/2013  11:36 AM         3,333,736 dbgeng.dll
26/09/2013  11:36 AM         1,403,496 dbghelp.dll
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           654,264 DbgHost.exe
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           614,328 DbgLib.dll
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           409,016 DbgSvc.exe
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           659,384 DebugDiag.Analysis.exe
25/09/2013  10:40 AM               227 DebugDiag.Analysis.exe.config
26/09/2013  11:36 AM         3,337,666 DebugDiag.chm
03/12/2013  06:48 PM           122,026 DebugDiag.chw
25/09/2013  11:16 AM         3,740,600 DebugDiag.Collection.exe
25/09/2013  11:19 AM           365,496 DebugDiag.DotNet.dll
25/09/2013  10:31 AM           237,394 DebugDiag.DotNet.xml
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           359,352 DebugDiag.RuleBuilder.exe
25/09/2013  11:19 AM            35,768 DebugDiag.WorkflowActivities.dll
03/12/2013  06:42 PM              Exts
25/09/2013  11:16 AM           209,848 LeakTrack.dll
25/09/2013  10:25 AM           502,272 Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.dll
25/09/2013  10:25 AM           105,984 Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll
25/09/2013  10:25 AM           542,720 Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll
26/09/2013  11:37 AM               720 Register.bat
09/06/2011  10:37 AM              Reports
03/12/2013  06:42 PM              Samples
03/12/2013  06:41 PM              Scripts
26/09/2013  11:36 AM           119,568 symsrv.dll
26/09/2013  11:36 AM                 1 symsrv.yes
26/09/2013  11:37 AM               771 Unregister.bat
03/12/2013  06:42 PM              x86Support
              23 File(s)     16,802,765 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  60,245,811,200 bytes free
```

The analyzer is in one but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read, DebugDiag is not supported on Windows server 2003.
See:
[... it's intended behavior.  Analysis on Windows Server 2003 is not supported.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugdiag/archive/2013/10/03/debugdiag-2-0-is-now-rtw.aspx)

---

Context from the linked page -

> Dani Avni 28 Oct 2013 6:52 AM #
> the analysis module is not available for install on windows 2003 server although i have .net 4 > installed there. is this the intended behavior or a bug?
>
> Wade Mascia 29 Oct 2013 9:55 AM #
> @Dani - it's intended behavior.  Analysis on Windows Server 2003 is not supported.  As a workaround, > instead of using the .msi you can xcopy the DebugDiag directory from another machine and run > register.bat.  Be sure the other machine is post-2003, and matches the bitness (32, 64) of your 2003 > machine.

Comment: You can do the analysis on another server, but must provide the path of the respective symbols files correctly. Use the environment variable _NT_SYMBOL_PATH for this.